# ASP.Net "Security.Principle.IsInRole" does not work on .Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

I have an application which currently checks whether a user is a member of an Active Directory group. The code is:

```
Dim UsersIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim Principal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(UsersIdentity)

        If Principal.IsInRole(GroupName) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

This works fine when we publish to IIS and the application pool is set to .Net 2.0, however when we change the app pool to .Net 4.0 that function always returns false.

MSDN suggests IsInRole is still a supported function, has anyone any ideas why it would not be working on .Net 4.0?   (IIS is set to Windows Auth).

Comment: .Net 4.0 Managed Pipeline Mode - Classic or Integrated?

Comment: Its set to Integrated. I switched it to Classic but it seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found that this works in .Net 4.0:

```
Dim UsersIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity
```

As opposed to getting the identity from System.Security.Principal.